# Serverless plugin domain manager not reducing the resource limit

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53, serverless-framework, serverless-plugins

I ran into the 200 resource limit on cloudformation when using serverless. I saw on the blog that using the domain manager will help mitigate this issue by freeing a few resources from the api gateway.

After implementing this I realized it did nothing to help resource limit. Do I need to do something else after this. I am not sure if I should remove my sls stack and redeploy it?

Answer (score 0):

All serverless does is transform some abstract configuration into CloudFormation templates (and other provider templates too.)

Adding a plugin to help you reconfigure the same stack won't reduce your number of resources that get generated.

The serverless blog has a great article on this, https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-workaround-cloudformation-200-resource-limit/.

The TL;DR is that there is a limit to resources in stacks so you have to break your stacks up.

You can:

- Split your stacks manually, create multiple projects to form your platform and use references between them; or
- Use a plugin to split the outputted CloudFormation template via:

  - [serverless-plugin-additional-stacks](https://github.com/SC5/serverless-plugin-additional-stacks)
  - [serverless-nested-stack](https://github.com/aditmalik-synechron/serverless-nested-stack)
  - [serverless-plugin-split-stacks](https://github.com/dougmoscrop/serverless-plugin-split-stacks)